# How to save non-english language/special characters in core data?

Tags: ios, core-data, character-encoding, utf

Language of string coming from server is **Herbew** and when i show directly that data to my view, the characters come right but next time when i try to fetch it from data base "**????**" comes instead of right characters!

//THIS IS WHERE I SAVE A CONTACT WITH DISPLAY NAME TO DB//

```
    -(BOOL)addContact:(ALContact *)userContact {

        ALDBHandler * dbHandler = [ALDBHandler sharedInstance];

        DB_CONTACT* existingContact = [self getContactByKey:@"userId" value:[userContact userId]];
        if (existingContact) {
            return NO;
        }

        BOOL result = NO;

        DB_CONTACT * contact = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"DB_CONTACT" inManagedObjectContext:dbHandler.managedObjectContext];
        contact.displayName = userContact.displayName;

        NSError *error = nil;
        result = [dbHandler.managedObjectContext save:&error];

        if (!result) {
            NSLog(@"addContact DB ERROR :%@",error);
        }

        return result;
}
```

Comment: You need to describe what your code is doing, because Core Data does not require any special steps to store non-English characters as strings.

Comment: @TomHarrington server sends this  "\U05de\U05ea\U05df \U05d0 \U05e6\U05f3\U05d0\U05d8" and in label it is showing rightly this ‫מתן א צ׳אט‬‎‎ its right upto now BUT when we save in ios database and fetch from it and it shows "????"
I tried encoding it before saving into db / decoding when fetching... no luck

Comment: If you don't post some code, no answer is possible. You're doing something wrong, but without some code nobody can really tell you what.

Comment: @TomHarrington I completely understand but the flow is going through many classes ! Its not a single method which is doing it all ! I will still try to add code bits with flow ! Thanks!

Comment: OK, so what is `userContact` and how does it get its value for `displayName`? That would seem to be a key detail.

Comment: @TomHarrington userContact is an Object subclass of a My-Json-Parsing-Class further subclass of NSObject which have a property "displayName" and it is acquired by the device from server during login. So, displayName is type of NSString, wherever i use it directly (by directly I mean fetching from server and displaying it in label as it is at that moment, it shows correctly But once i got it from server and saved to db, next time I retrieve it from db , it gets corrupted or what and it shows "??? ???" )

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116539/discussion-between-divjyot-and-tom-harrington).

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to tell exactly where things are going wrong (we could go round and round via discussion in comments for a long time), but the answer will be something like:

1. Core Data does not require any special steps to store non-English text. It just works. However...
2. String encodings are **very** easy to screw up, and are an extremely common source of errors. Somewhere in your code (maybe in multiple places) you're getting the encoding wrong, which causes bogus strings. It only looks like a Core Data problem because you're using this badly-encoded string with Core Data.

As an experiment I created a new Xcode project using the "Master-Detail Application" template, using Core Data. Then I added a field to the default "Event" entity called "name" and modified the UI to display this string.

Then I assigned your string as the value of "name":

[image: newEvent.name = @"מתןאצ׳אט";]

After creating a few instances, quitting and relaunching the app, I can verify that the string was saved correctly, retrieved intact, and displayed in the UI correctly:

[image: iOS Simulator screenshot]

So, stop looking at your Core Data code and start looking at every step of how you handle this string.

Comment: Got you! I am certain you are right now! I suspect that we had two user detail fetching calls from server first one is sending rightly encoded but as soon as we perform some tasks (which is retrieval from CoreData ) between those two things(fetching data and reflecting it) a second server is messing with encoding which saves bogus one in db! Thank you very much for your answers!!

Answer (score 1):

Rather than saving as String save it as NSdata.

Below code might help you in saving and retrieving it back.

```
var herbrewStrFromServer = "⌘" //Herbew String
let dataSaveCoreData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(herbrewStrFromServer) //Converting into Nsdata so as to save in coredata
let actualStringRetreived = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(dataSaveCoreData) as! String // retrieving it back from core data
```

Comment: Working with core data. Can you suggest weather there is any managedContext attribute to encode when we save the data.

Comment: When defining attribute make it as binary data rather than string. And convert your specific string into data and save into core data as you do for normal attributes.

Comment: Yes, I infact tried that with setting my xcmodel displayName attribute's type to Binary and its corresponding class attribute to NSData and while creating a db object, i converted the nsstring to using your code as well and UTF8 encoding as well . Both not working in this case.